# Static Initialization Design Ideas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, static, custom-attributes

Currently, my MVC 3 app has a dependency on a static class that is initialized in the Application_Start() like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MyDependency.Initialize();
}
```

With the static class looking more or less like the following:

```
public static class MyDependency
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        // Perform some I/O...
    }
}
```

This dependency is used in an attribute class, which comes with the caveat of having no run-time dependencies (hence the call to initialize in the Application_Start())

```
public class MyAttributeClass : ...
{
    public MyAttributeClass()
    {
        MyDependency.DoSomething(); //...
    }
}
```

Ultimately, other developers in our shop will have to use this API, and I'd like to see if there's a way to get rid of the line in the Application_Start() (an extra line of code in the Global.asax is likely to be a forgotten step)

For instance, is there a way the MyDependency class can "hook" into the pipeline without the needing to edit the Global.asax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a static constructor in `MyDependency`. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the MSDN explaining the functionality static constructors provide.

By using a static constructor you should then be able to perform all the IO you need, as the constructor will be run before any static members are accessed.

Comment: Yup this did it. I was under the (wrong) impression that the static constructor was called when the static class is first used. The MSDN article clarified things. Thank you

Comment: This certainly works. However, be very cautious that your static constructor does not throw any exception as has nasty consequences. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4737910/117625 and the warnings in the MSDN link from the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [WebActivator](http://nuget.org/packages/WebActivator). From [the wiki](https://bitbucket.org/davidebbo/webactivator/wiki/Home):

> WebActivator is a NuGet package that allows other packages to easily
>   bring in Startup and Shutdown code into a web application. This gives
>   a much cleaner solution than having to modify global.asax with the
>   startup logic from many packages.

Essentially, you'll need something like:

```
using System;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyDependency), "Initialize")]
public static class MyDependency
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        // Perform some I/O...
    }
}
```