# Is there a way to catch these Exceptions?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

Is there a way to catch these Exceptions? (I am not looking for "just put try/catch or on error goto around them"). I am trying to find out if these errors can be caught by something outside of them.

```
Public Class ABC
   Shared Sub New()
     throw new Exception("Ha!")
   End Sub
End Class
```

or this:

```
Public Class ABC
  Dim obj as Object = CreateObject()

  Public Function CreateObject()
    throw new Exception("Ha!")
  End Function
End Class
```

BTW, Putting these in my startup class's (it's a Windows form) as the first lines in "Shared Sub New()" isn't working:

```
AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Application_ThreadException
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException
```

Comment: It's rude to mention "On Error Goto" in public ;) Don't do it again.

Comment: They can be caught at any level in the call stack.  Maybe I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Fantius: the first one is thrown in a static constructor, which makes it a little more complicated than that. But the second can be caught anywhere you do `new ABC()`, as it is thrown in the constructor.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice that it was a static constructor.

Comment: I can't imagine why you would ever need to do something in a static (Shared) constructor that could throw an exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328465/type-initializer-static-constructor-exception-handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:
http://temujin.blogsome.com/2006/03/15/static-constructors-and-exceptions/ (now dead - [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20061026062633/http://temujin.blogsome.com/2006/03/15/static-constructors-and-exceptions/))

Key points:

> if an exception occurrs the runtime will allways wrap it in a TypeInitializationException

So try looking for a TypeInitializationException at the application/AppDomain level.  Also:

> the static constructor only is executed one time by the runtime, when the type is initialized; the second time the static field is accessed the initial exception will be thrown again

In a nutshell - don't do anything that might throw exceptions in static (Shared) constructors.  Move the code to static properties or methods or an instance constructor.

Comment: This is an interesting idea but there is no event to capture this. Can you give an example of a TypeInitializationException I can subscribe to. As you can imagine I can't put a try/catch in the second case. Not sure where I am supposed to go from this...